# Distro upgrade error from 18 to 20 LTS

Tags: kubuntu

I am trying to upgrade my Kubuntu 18 LTS (latest wit hall updates) to 20.04 LTS.
Below is what happen when I run update command and I'm wondering if anyone fixed that already:

> sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]
> Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,336 kB]
> Fetched 1,338 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
> authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg'  extracting
> 'focal.tar.gz'
>
> Reading cache
>
> Checking package manager Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree         Reading state information... Done Hit
> http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
> Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
> Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic
> InRelease                                             Hit
> https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease
> Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease [64.4
> kB]                                           Hit
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
> Fetched 64.4 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
> Reading package lists... Done     Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 197, in _get_from_and_to_version
> di.version('%s' % self.controller.fromDist).split()[0] AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```
>
> File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/focal", line 8, in
>
> sys.exit(main())                                                                                                   File
> "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py",
> line 238, in main
> if app.run():                                                                                                      File
> "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 2089, in run
> return self.fullUpgrade()                                                                                          File
> "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 1926, in fullUpgrade
> if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 924, in doPostInitialUpdate
> self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 99, in run
> func()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 118, in focalPostInitialUpdate
> self._get_from_and_to_version()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 203, in _get_from_and_to_version
> (r.version for r in di.get_all("object") AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all' Error in
> sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 497, in
> add_to_existing
> self.write(f)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 450, in write
> block = f.read(1048576)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position
> 1: invalid start byte
>
> Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 197, in _get_from_and_to_version
> di.version('%s' % self.controller.fromDist).split()[0] AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/focal", line 8, in 
> sys.exit(main())   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py",
> line 238, in main
> if app.run():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 2089, in run
> return self.fullUpgrade()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 1926, in fullUpgrade
> if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 924, in doPostInitialUpdate
> self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 99, in run
> func()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 118, in focalPostInitialUpdate
> self._get_from_and_to_version()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-hup3v_tw/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py",
> line 203, in _get_from_and_to_version
> (r.version for r in di.get_all("object") AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu is a desktop, all desktop releases use *deb* files and are *yy.mm* in format.  Ubuntu does have *yy* releases, however they are *snap* only, eg. Ubuntu Core 18, and Ubuntu Core 20 (and have a longer supported life than LTS on *yy.mm* releases). All server & desktop releases however use *deb* files and are *yy.mm* in format.

Comment: All right, thanks for the info. However what is that mean for me here? I am using upgrade  command I found on Kubuntu pages.

Comment: Your issue could be you've changed the default `python3` (or `python`) version.  If you enter `python -V; python3 -V`; what do you get?  Python3 should respond 3.8.2 for *bionic*  (your text is hard to read as you've used quoting instead of code "{}" block)

Comment: you're actually right, I change python to point into python3 indeed, I need to undone that then, thanks My python3 is still 3.6 while python gives python2.7

Comment: Sorry I made an error, 3.8.2 was for *focal*, what you said, ie. 3.6.5 should be *bionic*... I made a type when copying from my `rmadison python3` output (typed the wrong line), sorry.

Comment: I  now remember, I changed PIP to be python3, I think I have a mess there. Any idea how to fix it nicely ?

Comment: prev comment was stupid, I have Python 2.7.17 and Python 3.6.9, however both pip and pip3 runs python3, I can't find where is the file or link I changed, my bad.

Comment: That's the problem, *bionic* should have 3.6.7 (`python3 | 3.6.7-1~18.04    | bionic-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`), meaning tools that were built to use that version won't work, you'll need to restore your python3 default to the supported version 3.6.7 for upgrade to work (why you've python3 errors), or you could upgrade via re-install. However you changed the python3 version should be reversed.  (3.6.5 was original *bionic*, 3.6.7 was *bionic-updates*)

Comment: I believe I fit a bug here. When I look elsewhere I can see that I'm not alone with this. After digging a bit I got to the bottom of this. Here is the link to the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1874250